# When opening vscode using batch file, cmd opens and doesn't close

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code

When trying to open vscode folder using a batch file, Visual Studio opens up with that folder, but also a cmd window pops up and does not go away if you use exit command.

```
@echo off
start code "C:\GitHub\TestApp\testapp"
exit
```

VSCode opens up correctly, but also this window opens

[image: cmd window]

Comment: Have you tried without `start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That CMD window is associated with the VSCode instance that you just opened. Attempting to close it will terminate the application you started. (*in this case, VSCode*)

The `start xxx xxx...` command opens up a new cmd terminal to perform its action. Even though a new prompt appears, which can be used as a normal terminal itself, the VSCode process is inexorably linked to it as the parent process.

If your goal is to not launch a separate cmd window, then run:

`start code /b "C:\GitHub\TestApp\testapp"`

which just runs the command in the same window. The VSCode window is still inexorably bound to the current cmd window and will close if the cmd window disappears, but at least another cmd window isn't launched.

Windows doesn't have the capability to launch a program in the background from the terminal.

Comment: But i am able to close the cmd window and use the visual studio code instance still

Answer (score 6):

Using VSCode 1.52.1, the only way I could start it without having a cmd window open after exiting the batch script is:

```
explorer.exe "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

Note: it does not involve opening a specific local directory to work with. But maybe you can find a solution such as saving the folder as a workspace or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open recent folders. Plus, if you work only within that directory / workspace, or use it right before closing VSCode, it will be opened automatically at the next launch.

Comment: This is great to have VS Code reopen the previous session.

Comment: After running this command, you can use `call code` to open a new empty window, `call code folder_path` to open a folder in a new window, and `call code path_to_file` to open a file in the current window. The terminal does close at the end if VSCode is opened with explorer.exe first

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are actually invoking the batch file `code.cmd` which is located at `[VSCodePath]\bin\code.cmd`. The `code.cmd` file in turn invokes the actual VSCode executable `code.exe`

When invoking a batch file (`.BAT` or `.CMD`) using the `start` command, a new instance of CMD process will be created to handle the execution of the batch file, But it invokes the CMD process with the `/K` switch rather than `/C`

For example `start code.cmd` executes `cmd /k code.cmd`

It is the `/K` switch that causes the new cmd to remain open after finishing the execution of the batch file.

To resolve, instead of supplying the batch file directly the to the `start` command, execute it by an explicit CMD invokation:

```
@echo off
start cmd /C code "C:\GitHub\TestApp\testapp"
exit
```

Comment: This method still makes the window pop up, however it pops up as a blank terminal with no directory. And closes once you close visual studio code it closes as well

Comment: @TadasPetraitis, The reason that the terminal window remains open while vs code is running is that you are probably running `code.exe` directly. In that case vs code attaches itself to the parent console, causes the console to remain open until it is closed. To resolve, try to to invoke `code.cmd` explicitly: `start cmd /C code.cmd .....` however it causes it a terminal window to quickly popup and disappear. If don't like the popup flash add the `/b` switch to the `start` command parameters: `start /b cmd /c code.cmd .....`

Comment: Also you should be able to abandon the `start` command altogether and call the `code.cmd` file directly inside your own batch file: `call code.cmd "C:\GitHub\TestApp\testapp"`

Answer (score 0):

If all described solutions did not work for you, try making an ordinary Windows shortcut to `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" C:\path-to-project-folder-or-file`.

[image: Shortcut properties window]

Then call this shortcut in your `.bat` or `.cmd` script like that (assuming shortcut name is `shortcut`):

```
@echo off
start C:\path-to-shortcut-file\shortcut
```